# Socket operation on non-socket C

Tags: c, sockets

I am getting this error when trying to make an application to connect and listen to a port for data.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char * arg[]){   
int conn_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);      //Create the socket

struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(1234);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
int res = bind(conn_s, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

if(res < 0){
    printf("Error has occured\n");
}

FILE * stream = fdopen(conn_s, "w+");               //Create a stream for the socket
FILE * file = fopen("response2.txt", "w+");         //Create a file to store the output of the stream

char * line = NULL;    //Where each line of the stream will be stored in
size_t len = 0;        // The length of the line
ssize_t bytes;         //The size of the line in bytes

int lis = listen(conn_s, SOMAXCONN);
fcntl(lis, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

while(1) {
    conn_s = accept(lis, NULL, NULL);
    if(conn_s < 0){
        if((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
            continue;
        perror("Failed to accept connection");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    long conn_s_flags = fcntl(conn_s, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(conn_s, F_SETFL, conn_s_flags & ~O_NONBLOCK);

    while((bytes = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {   
        printf("%s\n", line);
        fwrite(line, sizeof(char), bytes, file);            
    }

    close(conn_s);
}
free(line);

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to connect to port 1234, listen to it and accept it to recieve data, but the error keeps occuring.

Also I am trying to test using netcat, but get a different error whenever nc is running on the port I specified.

Thanks

Comment: _but the error keeps occuring_: you need to me bore specific.

Comment: Exept for the fcntl, you don't do anything with the `conn_s` (before closing it)

Comment: Which error are you talking about?

Comment: `FILE * stream = fdopen(conn_s, "w+"); ` is useless, when used *before* the socket is accepted. `int lis = listen(conn_s, SOMAXCONN);` listen does **not** return a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

```
int lis = listen(conn_s, SOMAXCONN);
fcntl(lis, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
while(1) {
    conn_s = accept(lis, NULL, NULL);
```

`listen()` does not return a socket FD. It returns zero or -1. The second line is therefore erroneous, as is the following `accept()` call. It should be:

```
if (listen(conn_s, SOMAXCONN) == -1)
{
    perror("listen");
    return; // or whatever
}
fcntl(conn_s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
while(1) {
    int conn_c = accept(conn_s, NULL, NULL);
```

NB Don't lose `conn_s` by storing the result of `accept()` into it.